# TypeScript Array.prototype.map declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading, overriding

**Spec**

According to the [MDN specification for Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) map should be used like this...

```
var new_array = arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

**Problem**

TypeScript has several overloaded declarations for map, and this makes it very difficult to `extend Array<T>`.

I would expect to see this *(which is in lib.d.ts)*...

```
map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
```

But lib.d.ts also has these...

```
map<U>(this: [T, T, T, T, T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U, U, U, U, U];

map<U>(this: [T, T, T, T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U, U, U, U];

map<U>(this: [T, T, T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U, U, U];

map<U>(this: [T, T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U, U];
```

**Objection**

Since JavaScript does not allow method overloading, and neither does TypeScript for class implementation, I don't think that TypeScript should allow this for ambient declarations either.

**Questions**

1. Why does TypeScript allow overloaded signatures for ambient declarations?
2. How do I override the map implementation in a class that extends Array?

I've raised this on GitHub too...
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13785

**Note**

`ReadonlyArray<T>` only has a single signature for map, which is...

```
 map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: ReadonlyArray<T>) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
```

Comment: It's interesting that you didn't ask about what IMO would be the most important aspect here: _purpose_. As in *"why define all these overload signatures in the first place?"* -- And the answer to that would be the fact, that TypeScript has a type-concept of arrays with a finite amount of elements, such as `[number, number, number]` being a 3-element `number[]`. This is assignable both _to_ and _from_ `number[]`, but is not _precisely_ the same from the compiler's point of view. Also, these are also called tuple-types in some context, and can define not-necessarily inter-assignable elem types.

Comment: @JohnWeisz I get that concept of n-element arrays, but then why does this concept in this respect stop at 5-element arrays? Surely n could be infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) If it wouldn't be allowed to overload signatures in ambient declarations how would you get the different signatures in the native js functions/methods?
There are a lot of overloads in the `lib.d.ts` which reflects how the native js objects work.

(2) You need to tell the compiler that you're covering all of the possible declared signatures.
In your case you can do something like:

```
class A<T> extends Array<T> {
    map<U>(this: Array<U>, ...args: any[]);
    map<U>(this: Array<T>, callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[] {
        return [];
    }
}
```

The first overload signature takes care of the ones you don't want to bother with.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches different aspects of TypeScript. I'll handle them individually and then put them all together.

**Array<T>**

Interfaces serve a dual purpose in TypeScript:

1. They allow you to create "true" interfaces for other (not yet existing) classes to implement. When you implement it, you have to implement it entiriely, since the interface provides a guarantee of all its members being available.
2. They allow you to define the interface of an *already existent* javascript type. This is very useful when you want to use one of the many, many existent libraries and still have the advantages of static typing. These interfaces are usually defined in a `.d.ts` file (and `lib.d.ts` file contains the basic JavaScript types). These interfaces are tailored to the existing type and they are usually not meant for you to implement. You can though if you want, but you have to implement all its members.

The `Array<T>` interface is of the second kind and as such it is not meant for you to implement.

**`this` Parameters in Functions**

The `this:` parameter in the function definition is not a real parameter in the sense that you can pass arguments. It allows you specify which type you expect the `this` value in the function body to be. If you don't specify it, `this` will be of type `any`, which is often not very useful.

**Function/Method Overloading**

In TypeScript, functions and methods are not overloaded in the sense they are overloaded in languages like Java or C#. You cannot implement it more often than once, but you can define alternate signatures to allow static typing for functions that return variant types or use variant parameters. Especially in `.d.ts` definition files this is useful and often necessary, since existing libraries use the weak typing of JavaScript to return values or expect parameters of different types. That makes your objection false. You need function overloading to accommodate these JavaScript constructs.

**Tuples**

In a JavaScript array you can assign values of multiple types in each of its slots. In a TypeScript array definition you specify *one* type, which the complier enforces. To fill the gap, you can define *tuples*. A type like `[number, string, string]` translates to a JavaScript array `any[]` and TypeScript can still enforce static typing.

**Summary**

The array method overloads you object against in `Array<T>` introduce a statically typed `this` parameter in the event the array is an actual `[T, T]`, `[T, T, T]`, `[T, T, T, T]`, `[T, T, T, T, T]`. It does not imply that the array provides multiple `map` methods. It is the same method, but overloaded for some specific array types. It is provided in `lib.d.ts` and as such was not designed to be implemented by you. You can extend the underlying class (which is already there even without the interface), but the overloads don't hurt you (at least not in this case, since they only provide `this` parameters).

Comment: `Array` is in fact a class which you can extend, something you should have checked before posting this answer. All of your long explanations are probably known to the OP (based on what he asked about and how he asked it).

Comment: @NitzanTomer: I have checked (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts - search for "interface Array<T> {") and you seem to know the OP better than I do.

Comment: You will also see that after the `interface Array<T>` there's `interface ArrayConstructor` which defines the constructors and then there's `declare const Array: ArrayConstructor` which makes `Array` a class.

Comment: But more than that, just try to compile `class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> { }` and see that it works.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: I'll correct that part, nevertheless it is an interface in the sense that I have described in the post. The _class_ is already there, the _interface_ just defines its members.

Comment: That's irrelevant. The `Array` in runtime is a constructor function (almost) like any other class. The fact that it is defined in the definition file the way it is (interface and interface for the constructor) doesn't change the fact that it is a class. You can extend it in ts without the need to implement things yourself